# Metarig to Rigify Bendy bones lose settings

Tags: rigify

Trying to get Bendy bones from Metarig to Rigify with the Bendy settings in tact. And failing!
Can’t figure out what I am doing wrong.

The left side is a “basic.super_copy” rig type and it loses the Bendy info in rigify (stays stretchy though)
The right side is a “skin.stretchy_chain” that I extruded to add a chain. Rigify changes the start and stop points of bendy chain to handles, but they don’t work.( I can grab the controller and bend it though, controller is fine)
Working on this a while with different rig types and can’t seem to figure it out. What am I dong wrong? Any suggestions?
Thanks! (Top pic is metarig and bottom is Rigify?
[image: Metarig on top Rigify on bottom]

Comment: You could try adding you bendy bones controls to the rig as child of constraint

Comment: Thanks DV, sounds interesting. Not really sure how to do this. I see the child of constraint, but how would I add the bendy bone controls to it? Would I put the constraint on the DEF chain to the ORG chain? Could you explain a little how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should try setting the rig type to `basic.raw_copy` for bendy bone. Even set this rig type to the Def bones. Also after generating the rig you should tick *Deform* in every single bendy bone (unfortunately after every Re-Generating the rig as far as I know).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks D, I ended up building separate bones then attaching them to the final rig all at once (Parenting). I also wanted to keep the constraints which disappeared from the model when the rigify rig was created.
I'll try your suggestion on the next try!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial, stand on their own, and thoroughly explain the solution and required steps. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can, [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and how it works, perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating some steps and final result. See [How to write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), otherwise it may be converted to a comment.

Comment: By the way: You also have the option of merging two accounts into one if you are interested. You can find the instructions here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/contact (*Account Issue* > *I need to merge user profiles*)